# Content Security Policy (CSP) - why does a JS file have multiple hashes?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm looking at my browser's console and I see the following error:

[image]

These all pertain to the same JS file.

I'm trying to figure out what's the quickest way to make these error go away. I'm guessing I can put the given hash in my script declaration, something like:

```
<script src="/assets/scripts/main.js" integrity="sha256-oB/JYOK782SSJ0f0XEuF36INIpCa5BTEt/q8IEny8x8="></script>
```

Questions:

1. Is putting that hash as the value of the `integrity` attribute that correct way to handle this problem?
2. Why does it seem like one file has three hashes?

Comment: If it shows up with 3 different hashes which all use the same hash algorithms (sha256) then it is not the same content. It might be the same URL which for each request creates a slightly different content though. In this case you cannot rely on a specific hash of the resource content, but need to rely on a magic nonce instead - see [MDN nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce) on how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it shows up with 3 different hashes which all use the same hash algorithms (sha256) then it is not the same content. It might be the same URL which for each request creates a slightly different content though. In this case you cannot rely on a specific hash of the resource content, but need to rely on a magic nonce instead - see [MDN nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce) on how to use it.